# Are we not allowed to create a private method inside a PHPUnit file?

Tags: php, unit-testing, web

I have written a phpUnit file and 1 test which ran fine. I noticed that a huge chunk of the test will be reusable in my next tests, so I decided to extract a private method. and when I ran it again, I got:

```
"Test method "<method name>" in test class "<Test Class Name>" is not public.
```

Are we really not allowed to write private methods?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like all methods that starts with "test" are treated as a separate test. I ended up renaming my private method.